# C# asp.net How can i single line else less if

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<h3><%= User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? true : User.Identity.Name; %></h3>
```

I'd like to write a one-line code that returns the member's name when the member is already logged in.
But the IsAuthenticated code already returns true,
so do i need to use true ?
Also, I don't want to do anything unless user not logged in.
in this case. When you want to write concise code in one line. Which code would be best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way that you can do this, By using `Tag helper` which explained in [this article](https://dev.to/uthmanrahimi/render-html-tags-based-on-condition-in-aspnet-core-4chm), you can rewrite your code like this:

```
<h3 condition="User.Identity.IsAuthenticated">
  User.Identity.Name
</h3>
```

Condition tag helper implementation is :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace CustomTagHelpers.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = nameof(Condition))]
     public class ConditionTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public bool Condition { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            if (!Condition)
            {
                output.SuppressOutput();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can it be used in asp.net framework webform ?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Tag helper is not exist in `asp.net web forms`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this `<h3>@(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? User.Identity.Name :"")</h3>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) which has the form:

```
condition ? consequent : alternative
```

In your case this would be:

```
<h3><%= User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? User.Identity.Name : string.Empty; %></h3>
```